# How to calculate valid number of combinations, given a two array list?

Tags: java, algorithm, while-loop, combinations, combinatorics

Given List of datacenters which are `dc1`, `dc2`, `dc3` and list of machines `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `h4` as mentioned below -

```
Datacenters = dc1, dc2, dc3
Machines = h1, h2, h3, h4
```

I want to generate below combinations only for the above list -

```
a)  {dc1=h1, dc3=h3, dc2=h2}

b)  {dc1=h2, dc3=h4, dc2=h3}

c)  {dc1=h3, dc3=h1, dc2=h4}

d)  {dc1=h4, dc3=h2, dc2=h1}
```

In general, Each datacenter in the each pass should get alternate machines/hosts. They should not get same machines. For example in `a` as shown above - `dc1 gets h1`, `dc2 gets h2`, `dc3 gets h3` so all the machines are different for each datacenters. And in the second pass as shown in `b` - now `dc1 gets h2` (becuase dc1 already got h1 in the first pass), `dc2 got h3` (bcoz dc2 already got h2 in the first pass), and `dc3 got h4`(bcoz dc3 already got h3 in the first pass) and etc etc.

And one more example -  if I have only three hosts, then below combination I am supposed to get only -

```
Datacenters = dc1, dc2, dc3
Machines = h1, h2, h3    

{dc1=h1, dc3=h3, dc2=h2}
{dc1=h2, dc3=h1, dc2=h3}
{dc1=h3, dc3=h2, dc2=h1}
```

So I came up with the below code which works perfectly fine without any issue -

```
public class DataCenterMapping {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    DatacenterMachineMapping dcm = new DatacenterMachineMapping(Arrays.asList("dc1", "dc2", "dc3"), Arrays.asList(
        "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4"));

        // is there any way to precalculate number of combinations 
        // instead of using while loop here?
        while (true) {
            Map<String, String> coloHost = dcm.getDatacenterMachineMapping();
            System.out.println(coloHost);
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : coloHost.entrySet()) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my class which does all the work -

```
class DatacenterMachineMapping {

    private boolean firstCall = true;
    private int hostListIndex = 0;
    private List<String> datacenterList, hostList;
    private Map<String, Set<String>> dataCenterHostsMap = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();

    public DatacenterMachineMapping(List<String> datacenterList, List<String> hostList) {
    this.datacenterList = datacenterList;
    this.hostList = hostList;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getDatacenterMachineMapping() {
    Map<String, String> datacenterMachineMapping = new HashMap<String, String>();
    if (!firstCall) {
        if (hostListIndex <= 0) {
        hostListIndex = hostList.size();
        }
        hostListIndex--;
    } else {
        firstCall = false;
    }
    for (String datacenter : datacenterList) {
        if (hostListIndex == hostList.size()) {
        hostListIndex = 0;
        }
        if (addDataCenterHost(datacenter, hostList.get(hostListIndex))) {
        datacenterMachineMapping.put(datacenter, hostList.get(hostListIndex++));
        }
    }
    hostListIndex--;
    return datacenterMachineMapping;
    }

    private boolean addDataCenterHost(String datacenter, String host) {
    Set<String> dataCenterHostSet = dataCenterHostsMap.get(datacenter);
    if (dataCenterHostSet == null) {
        dataCenterHostSet = new HashSet<String>();
        dataCenterHostsMap.put(datacenter, dataCenterHostSet);
    }
    return dataCenterHostSet.add(host);
    }
}
```

**Problem Statement:-**

The only problem is I have a while loop which will keep on running always which is not what I want. I am trying to precalculate number of valid combinations before hand then I can use the for loop to iterate that.

Is there any way I can precalculate the number of valid combinations instead of using while loop in my above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming there are more machines than there are datacenters.  In which case your answer is:

```
hostList.size();
```

You can always generate the following sets:

```
Set 1: (1,1), (2,2), ... (n,n)
Set 2: (1,2), (2,3), ... (n,n+1%m)
...
Set m: (1,m), (2,m+1 % m), ... (n,(n + m-1) % m)
```

Note that:

```
(m + 1) % m   = 1
(n + m-1) % m = n-1
```

So it is really:

```
Set 1: (1,1), (2,2), ... (n,n)
Set 2: (1,2), (2,3), ... (n,n+1%m)
...
Set m: (1,m), (2,1), ... (n,n-1)
```

In fact...your code can just be:

```
public List<Map<String, String>> createMappings(List<String> datacenters, List<String> hosts) {
    List<Map<String, String>> result = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    for(int i = 0; i < hosts.size(); i++) {
        Map<String, String> row = new HashMap<String,String>();
        for(int j = 0; j < datacenters.size(); j++) {
            String datacenter = datacenters.get(j);
            int hostIndex = (j + i) % hosts.size();
            String host = hosts.get(hostIndex);
            row.put(datacenter, host);
        }
        result.add(row);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion on this. I am stuck on similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971988/find-the-combinations-given-n-number-of-box-with-x-number-of-balls). It's a similar problem but the catch is the number of balls can be different in each boxes. So not sure how should I extend your solution to adapt to this use case. I use ball and box there just to make people understand better.

Comment: Can you help me on that post if possible? I am still stuck on it and not able to figure out a solution for that.. Any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

number of valid combinations = Datacenters * machines;